# When and why I should use NamedNativeQuery or NamedQuery annotation

Tags: jpa

Just want to know when and why I should use the following annotations with Entities:
@NamedNativeQuery
@NamedQuery

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @NamedQuery: same query is being used at multiple places with different values of the parameters????

Comment: Can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8806270/366964

Answer (score 0):

when your existing project contains DB specific query and your TL says to you don't change it than go for @NamedNativeQuery otherwise use @NamedQuery . But it is good practise to use @NamedQuery