# Hibernate named query issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I have below name query

```
@NamedQuery(name="ScInstantTrack.getCustomerDetails", 
query="select b.cardDetail.mstCustomer.customerId, last_day(b.endDate), " +
        "LISTAGG(b.txnId,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b.endDate), " +
        "count(b.txnId), sum(b.amount), sum(b.balanceAmt), sum(b.redemptionAmt) " +
        "from ScInstantTrack b " +
        "where b.cardNo = b.cardDetail.cardBarcode " + 
        "AND b.cardDetail.mstCustomer.customerId = :customerId " + 
        "and b.startDate <= trunc(:todayDate) " + 
        "and b.endDate >= trunc(:todayDate) " + 
        "and b.cardDetail.mstStatus.statusId = 3003 group by b.cardDetail.mstCustomer.customerId, last_day(b.endDate)")
```

When I am executing this query then getting below error :

```
unexpected token: WITHIN
```

I am using Oracle Database.

Why I am getting this error? How to solve this issue?

Comment: First of all - show us whole query execution code; secondly - tell us which database is under the Hibernate hood (I'm guessing that Oracle)... You can also format pasted query - for readability.

Comment: Please check my update question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `@NamedNativeQuery` instead of `@NamedQuery`.

Also check [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752454/difference-between-namedquery-and-namednativequery-in-jpa-eclipselink) of difference between them.

Basically you are using expressions that are exclusive in Oracle DB. In other words - you want to execute **native query** (query in native for Oracle DB language). Named queries use `Java Persistence Query Language` (HQL i.e.).

Comment: I don't want to use @NamedNativeQuery. I am using only namedQuery. How can I use the same query in namedquery?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty If you have to use `@NamedQuery` you have to „translate” your native Oracle query to HQL/JPQL but, it may be difficult or, as someone mentioned, even impossible...

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the listtag functionality in namedquery?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty I haven't heard about sth like that in HQL but i doesn't mean that there's no equivalent at all. Try to search or create anoter question.

Answer (score 0):

The error happen because `LISTAGG` is an oracle specific function.
That function is not avaliable in HQL and there is nothing you can use instead for HQL.

In order to get the result you have to use a `SQLQuery` wich perform native SQL queryes. This way You have to implement a version of thw query for each database, but it will work.